Vertex AI Metadata Store Error: Overloaded: too many retries per request. (old status: generic::UNAVAILABLE: Backend is unavailable.)
I've currently provisioned an instance of the Vertex AI Metadata Store on a GCP Project without any Vertex AI Pipelines Running yet.
I wanted to verify if terraform was able to deploy the Metadata Store instance successfully via GCP, but I'm getting this error when I open the metadata store and select the region I deployed the instance to: Overloaded: too many retries per request. (old status: generic::UNAVAILABLE: Backend is unavailable.)
enter image description here
I can see that if I select a different region, the error would show up as Requested Metadata Store default not found
enter image description here
What would be the best way to verify if the Metadata Store Instance was provisioned successfully?
Somehow I haven't tried anything yet, because we're not allowed to run a Vertex AI Pipeline yet until we get all the approvals we've needed.
